# Swift closure syntax

Tags: swift, closures

I have following code that work:

```
let obsScan = source.scan(0, accumulator: +)
let obsReduce = source.reduce(0, accumulator: +)

let obs = Observable.zip(obsScan, obsReduce) { scan, reduce in
        return "scan - \(scan), reduce - \(reduce)"
}
```

I want to rewrite it, using auto complete closure syntax, and i ended up with:

```
let obs = Observable.zip(obsScan, obsReduce, resultSelector: { (scan, reduce) -> _ in
         return "scan - \(scan), reduce - \(reduce)"
})
```

However, that code throw me multiple errors:

> Contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which
>   cannot be implicitly ignored Consecutive statements on a line must be
>   separated by ';' Expected expression

I can't understand why i use tab to autocomplete function with closure, and when i fill arguments i got an errors?

Whole function declared like that:

```
 public static func zip<O1, O2>(_ source1: O1, _ source2: O2, resultSelector: @escaping (O1.E, O2.E) throws -> RxSwift.Observable.E) -> RxSwift.Observable<RxSwift.Observable.E> where O1 : ObservableType, O2 : ObservableType
```

Comment: What's wrong with the working code? The trailing closure syntax looks cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @vadian nothing, i just want to understand how to things work and why i can't write compiling code using auto suggestion with tab..

Comment: What is `Observable`, what are `obsScan, obsReduce`? – As always, a *self-contained* example would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR i did edit my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you waiting for. But this should work:

```
let obs = Observable.zip(obsScan, obsReduce, resultSelector: { scan, reduce in
         return "scan - \(scan), reduce - \(reduce)"
})
```

Comment: great, its work, now my question is - why auto complete syntax not working and throw an errors? i mean, when i use tab to auto complete functions and fill fields.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, Swift syntax is rather complicated. XCode really do much work. Maybe bug. Or not enough memory. Or just try to wait. This is not a human being. This is just an algorithm:)